# PHP OOP MySQL (WAMP) Variable Scope

Tags: php, mysql, scope

I'm having issues with scope; I have read multiple TUTS on using OOP PHP with MySQL and I'm still having issues.. so here it goes:
I have a variable ($GetUsersSQL) which houses the MySQL SELECT for retrieving the user data to populate the tables. However, when trying to use an MySQL UPDATE with this data; it says that the POST data is empty. Here's what I have as it stands (Forgive me for the bandaid fixes in the code).

```
Class Lib
{
        //public variables are still not retrieved by uploaddata method.
        public $rank;
        public $username;
        public $regiment;
        public $EventsRan;
        public $RankUp;
        public $DatePromoted;
        public $ReadNextRank;
        public $TimeReady;
        public $registered;
        public $ontag;
        public $Notes;
        public $GetUsersSQL;

    function Connection($host,$user,$password,$datab){
        $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die(mysql_error());
            if (isset($con))
                {
                    $db = mysql_select_db($datab);
                }
        $LoginSQL = /**mysql_query("SELECT regiment FROM Users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$userpassword'")**/ mysql_query("SELECT * FROM NewOrder");

        $regiment = $LoginSQL;
    }
    function GetUsers($rank){
    $GetUsersSQL =/** mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE regiment='$regiment' ORDER BY rank DESC")**/ mysql_query("SELECT * FROM NewOrder where rank='$rank'");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($GetUsersSQL))
                {
                echo '
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    <input  type="text" value="'.$row['Rank'].'" id="rank"></td>
                    <td><input  type="text" value="'.$row['Name'].'" id="name"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="'.$row['Regiment'].'" id="regiment"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="'.$row['Events Ran'].'" id="EventsRan"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="'.$row['Rank Up?'].'" id="RankUp"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="'.$row['Read next Rank'].'" id="ReadyNextRank"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="'.$row['Date Promoted'].'" id="DateLastPromoted"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="'.$row['Time ready'].'" id="TimeReady"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="'.$row['Registered'].'" id="Registered"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="'.$row['On Tag?'].'" id="OnTag"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="'.$row['Notes'].'" id="Notes"></td>
                ';
                }


        }
        public function __UploadData()
            {
                return $this->GetUsersSQL;
                //this is still broken
                if (isset($_POST['rank']))
                {
                    $this->rank = $_POST['rank'];
                    $this->name = $_POST['name'];
                    $this->regiment = $_POST['regiment'];
                    $this->EventsRan = $_POST['EventsRan'];
                    $this->RankUp = $_POST['RankUp'];
                    $this->DatePromoted = $_POST['DateLastPromoted'];
                    $this->ReadNextRank = $_POST['ReadyNextRank'];
                    $this->TimeReady = $_POST['TimeReady'];
                    $this->registered = $_POST['Registered'];
                    $this->ontag = $_POST['OnTag'];
                    $this->Notes = $_POST['Notes'];

                    $Query = mysql_query("UPDATE gfy SET rank='$this->rank', name='$this->name',ReadNextRank ='$this->ReadNextRank', regiment='$this->regiment', EventsRan='$this->EventsRan', RankUp='$this->RankUp', DatePromoted='$this->DatePromoted', timeReady='$this->Timeready',registered='$this->registered',ontag='$this->ontag' notes='$this->notes' WHERE name='$this->name'")or die(mysql_error());
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'EMPTY';
                }

            }
}
```

Made the following change since 1/13/2013 1:11AM Pacific Time:
To GetUsers($rank): $this->GetUsersSQL = '...';
To _UploadData(): isset was changed to isset($this->rank) and query now uses '".$this->rank."'... vs '$rank'

Comment: Anyway, you should **NOT** use $_POST/$_GET or any other superglobals within your classes. Refer to Martin Fowlers article on [Dependency Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) for further information.

Comment: In addition, you are using unchecked values in your SQL statements. Please do not directly embed request values in your SQL, but sanitize them first e.g. checking for the correct types and using at least mysql_real_escape. You should think about using PDO_MYSQL instead of the deprecated ext/mysql and taking prepared statements into account. This solves at least the basic problem of embedding values directly into the SQL string.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I'll do my best with what everyone has given and see how it works out.

Answer (score 1):

In your `__UploadData()` you are using

```
public function __UploadData()
{
    return $this->GetUsersSQL; // execution is being terminated here
    $this->rank = $_POST['rank']; // out of reach
    $this->name = $_POST['name']; // out of reach
    // more code here
}
```

In this case, because of `return` keyword here `return $this->GetUsersSQL` is returning before it goes further.
Also in your `GetUsers()` function you have

```
function GetUsers($rank){
    $GetUsersSQL = "...";
    // ...
}
```

You should use

```
$this->GetUsersSQL = "...";
```

Also replace following line

```
mysql_query("UPDATE gfy SET rank='$this->rank', name='$this->name',ReadNextRank ='$this->ReadNextRank', regiment='$this->regiment', EventsRan='$this->EventsRan', RankUp='$this->RankUp', DatePromoted='$this->DatePromoted', timeReady='$this->Timeready',registered='$this->registered',ontag='$this->ontag' notes='$this->notes' WHERE name='$this->name'")or die(mysql_error());
```

with

```
mysql_query("UPDATE gfy SET rank='".$this->rank."', name='".$this->name."'...");
```

Comment: Okay, I made the suggested changes and removed the return. However, I'm still running into the issue that the _UploadData() is still empty after making the suggested change to GetUsers($rank). How do I get the POST data into _UploadData()?

Comment: Changes were made; the variables in _UploadData() are still empty.